# what is host in SMTP in delphi

Tags: delphi, smtp

I am having one application which sends the email. It uses the NMSMTP component. In the NMSMTP.host is 'MAILHOST'. I am trying to find what is that MAILHOST and where the value is stored? How can I set that Host value?

I am able to connect using NMSMTP.connect but when trying to use NMSMTP.sendMail then I am getting error '554 mail from abc.com rejected for policy reason'

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The host is the email server for outgoing mail for the email account you're using to send the mail. For example, if your email address is `Naren@example.com`, and your email server for outgoing mail is `smtp.example.com`, your SMTP host is `smtp.example.com`.

What exactly goes before `.example.com` depends on what your server was configured to use. You'll have to check with the ISP providing the email account to find out what the proper host is, as it depends on how it was configured. (There's no "standard" SMTP host name for a domain.)

Comment: if NMSMTP.connected is true that means its connected to the server? Right? then any idea about error i m getting while sending mail?

Comment: Yes. There's a policy at `abc.com` about accepting mail the way you're trying to send it. :-) You're not providing any other information, though, so it's hard to say what the problem might be. Your question was "What is host in NMSMTP?", which is what I answered. I'd guess it's the from name or login info you're using, though. (BTW, you do know that the NM controls have been discontinued for years? They're ActiveX controls, unsupported by the vendor any longer AFAIK, and were replaced with Indy components more than a decade ago.)

Comment: thats true.. :) that SMTP server is configured by someone. Might i done have access.. As I abc.com is my mail id. Previously it was the other persons id.

Comment: yes i know that its very old but all applications are built on that platform. . once i get stability on these application then plan is to move to latest version.. :) :)