# How to send mails using TNMSMTP component delphi

Tags: delphi

I am trying send the emails using the lotus notes using TNMSMTP component. What steps i should follow to connect the lotus notes through application. There are 2 properties one is Host and another is User id. What should i mention in that properties i am not getting. Can anyone please help. 
thanks.

Comment: In [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12081975/33732), you indicated that you already knew how to send mail, but that the mail server was rejecting your message due to policy restrictions. Have you regressed, so that you actually *don't* know how to send e-mail? Or did you instead mean to ask why you're getting that response from your mail server? Or can you send mail elsewhere, and you really need specific help with how to send via a Notes server?

Comment: yes thats correct, i have one application to that i m trying to restore. for that i recalling all the steps and trying if that will work.

Comment: A much more Modern solution would be Indy 10 with the IdSMTP component and some helpers which allows you to use SMTP+TLS and SMTP+SSL, which for many SMTP purposes these days, is pretty essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the host, you can usually just use the name of your Domino server (the one the Notes client connects to - the one you can ping by name from a command window). You can see the name by seeing what server your mail database is on, or watching the lower left part of the status bar when first logging on to Notes.

For the user ID, it's the name you use to log into Notes to get to your mailbox and calendar.

For this to work, though, your Domino server has to be configured to allow SMTP mail to be sent. Most of them aren't, AFAIK, to prevent spamming through the server by malware.

Comment: Got the user id but how to domino server?

Comment: Naren, if your question is really how to programmatically detect the user's Domino server, then that's a very different question from how to send mail with a TNMSMTP component. You should either edit the question to ask what you really want, or post a new question. Either way, it's clear to me that your question as it currently appears isn't really what you want.

Comment: I told you that. :-) Log in to Notes, and see where your mail database is stored (in the lower left of the status bar in Notes itself, it says `Connected to server "somename"`), or see where your mail database is stored (right-click `Mail`, choose `Properties`, and get the server name from the `Database` tab).

Comment: Thanks to all.. Finally resolved all problems and successully rebuilt that application.. :) gr8 help and gr8 site.